# open suggestion for HTML attributes without ctrl+space in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

How can I see suggestion list when add new attribute to HTML tag without `ctrl + space` in *visual studio code*. (like *webStorm*).

actually I want open suggestion (Autocomplete) List when I type a Character.

I also installed the **IntelliSense**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure that your question is understandable to others. It looks like your question is not finished yet, since it is completely unclear--please explain much more.

Answer (score 0):

open `VS Code` open *command palette* by press `ctrl + shift + p` in *windows os* or `cmd + shift + p` in *Mac os* then write `open settings (json)` all settings list will open you can search for any setting you want to change in `vs code`, search for `editorsuggestions` all settings related with suggestions will open you can edit to suit your needs.

Comment: Previously, what you said had come to my mind, and this, was not my solution.

Comment: settings (json) or settings ui panel is the only place you can disable or enable any of -vscode- settings there you can enable -suggestions list- you didn't describe your question clearly or there's something broken on your -version- try to reinstall -vscode-.

Answer (score 0):

1. Adjust your VScode page into HTML from the bottom side.
2. Then go to extensions. Install

> "HTML Snippets"

.
3. Restart Vscode.
4. Then when you type

> "html5-boilerplate"

keyword, all boilerplate codes will be
added in your page.